# How to ignore deprecation warnings in astropy 3.2?

Tags: python-3.x, astropy

I recently updated Astropy to the new 3.2(.1) version. Suddenly a lot of AstropyDeprecationWarnings started to appear. 
I used to deal with them in this way:

```py
from astropy.utils.exceptions import AstropyDeprecationWarning
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category = AstropyDeprecationWarning)
```

However, with this new Astropy version, the filter is basically ignored and the warnings keep showing.
It is not a vital problem, the code works of course, but I would like to get rid of them because they make the output more difficult to read. Is there a way to solve this problem? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

The two warnings that I see more often are:

```py
WARNING: AstropyDeprecationWarning: astropy.extern.six will be removed in 4.0, use the six module directly if it is still needed [astropy.extern.six]
WARNING: AstropyDeprecationWarning: Composition of model classes will be removed in 4.0 (but composition of model instances is not affected) [astropy.modeling.core]
```

I think the second warning arises because of this line of code where I am combining a Gaussian model + a background:

```py
    model = models.Gaussian1D(amplitude = flux.max()*0.9, mean = 0., stddev = size) \
            + models.Const1D(amplitude = flux.min()*0.9)
```

I have no idea where the first warning comes from. I do not explicitly import astropy.extern.six (I actually do not know what it is) so it might be something related to the second warning or from a third party code.

**Edit v2:**

I investigated this a little bit more since the combination of models is not responsible for the warnings as I first thought. Apparently the astropy.extern.six warning arises from:

```py
from astroquery.ned import Ned
```

While the composition of model classes warning arises from:

```py
import photutils as ph
```

Comment: I don't think there's any reason Astropy 3.2 would have made it so that deprecation warnings can suddenly no longer be filtered.  Exactly what warnings are you getting, and from what code are they coming?  Perhaps the root cause of the warnings should be fixed; after all that's the purpose of the warnings.  It depends though, if it's coming from third-party code or your own code of course...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I edited the main question with the details you asked for.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I don't have an immediate solution off the top of my head, but that should help point the wait toward one. It is strange--from your own code I don't think you should be getting either of those warnings.

Comment: OK thanks for your help anyway!